# Spring recipes Book : AOP issue

Tags: java, spring-aop

Was reading Spring recipes and trying out some AOP related stuff .The explanation seemed pretty good and when i tried to run the examples , I got the following error :
I was just trying to run the sample code ,no changes at all.Any idea what i could be missing? (i added commons logging/aspectjrt.jar and aspectjweaver.jar to my classpath)

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1097)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:661)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.apress.springrecipes.calculator.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception already says, what your problem is:

> ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader] does NOT provide an
>   'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom
>   LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent:
>   -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar

Try the command line option.

Comment: -javaagent:C:\springjars\spring\spring-framework-3.1.0.M2\dist\org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.M2.jar .                    This worked fine. Thanks.